# Vagrant provision writing PATH variable to .profile

Tags: linux, bash, vagrant

Hi I'm trying to add a directory to the path directly on my vagrant provision but something didn't work as expected. I'm using this line

```
echo PATH=\""$"PATH:/opt/paraviewopenfoam410/bin\" >> /home/vagrant/.profile
```

If I use it inside a terminal works as expected adding at the of the `.profile` the following line

```
PATH="$PATH:/opt/paraviewopenfoam410/bin"
```

But when using in vagrant provision the result is:

```
PATH="PATH:/opt/paraviewopenfoam410/bin"
```

Missing the `$` symbol and breaking the `PATH` variable

Comment: Does vagrant do its own variable escaping? Dequoting? etc.? Could this just be an issue of needing to escape more? Also using `\"\$PATH...\"` might read a little cleaner.

Comment: @EtanReisner doing so will resolve the $PATH variable and output the result not put `$PATH` (name not the value) in the file

Comment: Doing what? Escaping the `$`? That's all your quoting games are doing just with more characters. Again, unless vagrant is doing its own variable expanding, etc. in which case you probably just have a quoting issue. (Try `echo \""$"PATH -- \$PATH\"` and at your shell prompt see what you get.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the `"` it will resolve variable so no matter how you put it and escape it, vagrant will resolve the `$PATH` variable and output the result in your `.profile`

If you just want to have plain text `$PATH` you just need to do with `'`

```
echo PATH=\'$PATH:/opt/paraviewopenfoam410/bin\' >> /home/vagrant/.profile
```

will work just fine

Comment: thank I didn't know about this, I always thought that the provision script runs like a bash script without variable evaluation or substitutions. Thanks again, works perfectly